# Copy a file and rename it to multiple files

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a master file that I would like to copy and rename to multiple names using excel. I have a column that carry all these number but I want also to add a master name at the end of every number. I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Could you please help me ?

For example,

Master file name is PC schematic.

Copied files
1_PC
2_PC
3_PC
4_PC

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your request -- do you want to save the master workbook as many workbooks based on a column of numbers inside the master workbook? Or would you like to create many worksheets from the master workbook column? Also, could you post your code so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Sub SaveFiles()


Dim masterName as string, saveName as String
Dim z 'Used to gather the array of numbers
Dim RowCountA

masterName = "_PC"

'Assuming the sheet with the numbers is in sheet one, column A
RowCountA - Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row

z = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(1).Resize(RowCountA, 1)

For i = 0 to RowCountA - 1
    saveName = z(i,1) & masterName
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Name:=saveName
Next i

End Sub
```

You might need to modify it a little bit to suit your needs but that should give you a good start.